# Error in regularization

Tags: r

I am using example from ML_Hackers_for_masters book of chapter 6 text regression and using the code provided in book but when i run the code given below

```
ranks <- read.csv(file.path( 'oreilly.csv'),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

set.seed(1) 
library('glmnet')
performance <- data.frame()
for (lambda in c(0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 5)) {
  for (i in 1:50) {
    indices <- sample(1:100, 80)
    training.x <- x[indices,]
    training.y <- y[indices]
    test.x <- x[-indices,]
    test.y <- y[-indices]
    glm.fit <- glmnet(training.x, training.y)
    predicted.y <- predict(glm.fit, test.x, s = lambda)
    rmse <- sqrt(mean((predicted.y - test.y) ^ 2))
    performance <- rbind(performance, data.frame(Lambda = lambda, Iteration = i, RMSE = rmse))
    }
  }
```

> Error in x[indices, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Please suggest me how to remove this error. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I am not able to understand what is x. Please check the dimension of x. 
The error message basically means that x is a vector or something like that. I can reproduce the error using below code.

```
x <- c(1:100)
ind <- sample(1:100, 80)
x[ind,]

Error in x[ind, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

From this code you can understand that because x is a vector, and I am trying to apply the matrix operation on it, hence the error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I converted my x into matrix earlier